# $this->tableGateway->adapter->select();の結果を、bufferに入れる方法

Tags: php, zend-framework

Zend Framework 2.5でSELECT処理について、以下の違いを知りたいです。

【Modelでのソース】

1.TableGatewayのセレクト機能

```
$resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select();
return $resultSet;
```

2.$statement->execute();

```
$sql = new Sql( $this->tableGateway->adapter );
$select = $sql->select();
$select->from('hogehoge');
// 作成したクエリを使用してステートメントを作成する
$statement = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select);
$resultSet = $statement->execute();
return $resultSet;
```

上記1では、取得したデータを複数回foreachで使用するため、bufferに入れています。

```
$resultSet->buffer();
```

上記2では、同様の処理をしても、bufferの機能が利用できず、foreachが複数回実行できません。
以下のエラーが発生します。

```
This result is a forward only result set, calling rewind() after moving forward is not supported
```

お手数をおかけしますが、対応方法をご教授いただけますでしょうか？
以上です、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2.$statement->execute();

```
$result = $statement->execute();
```

executeメソッドの返り値はResultSetオブジェクトではなく、Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Resultオブジェクトです。

一般的には、このResultオブジェクトをResultSetオブジェクトに整形（初期化）しなければなりません。

```
$sql = new Sql( $this->tableGateway->adapter );
$select = $sql->select();
$select->from('hogehoge');
// 作成したクエリを使用してステートメントを作成する
$statement = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select);
$result = $statement->execute();

// 取得したResultオブジェクトを任意の形式に整形
$resultSet = new ResultSet();
$resultSet->initialize($result);

return $resultSet;

//この時点で$resultSet->buffer();するとTableGatewayと同様の挙動になる。
```